# How to get a collection with some some fields excluded from some documents?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection of characters with the following information:

```
{
  { 
    name: "Character1",
    user_id: "user1"
  },
  {
    name: "Character2",
    user_id: "user2"
  }
}
```

Now I would like on the Client side to receive a collection as follows:
If I'm user1 I will get this:

```
{
  { 
    name: "Character1",
    user_id: "user1"
  },
  {
    name: "Character2",
  }
}
```

Basically stripping the user_id from any character that does not belong to that user.

What I did was:
return Characters.find({},{fields: {user_id:0} } );

How would I make it keep the field for the current user?

Comment: you have the information of the logged in userid in Meteor.userId() on the client or userId in every meteor method on the server. Why not use that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would set up two subscriptions, one for a person's characters and another for all characters (which removes the fields you don't want published). The results will get merged.

A little more information per the [DDP spec](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/livedata/DDP.md):

> The client maintains one set of data per collection. Each subscription
>   does not get its own datastore, but rather overlapping subscriptions
>   cause the server to send the union of facts about the one collection's
>   data. For example, if subscription A says document x has fields `{foo:
>   1, bar: 2}` and subscription B says document `x` has fields `{foo: 1,
>   baz:3}`, then the client will be informed that document `x` has fields
>   `{foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}`. If field values from different subscriptions
>   conflict with each other, the server should send one of the possible
>   field values.

Comment: This is exactly what I have done, but the other way around. I first send just the names and then update my own character with the additional information.